# Небезопасный код C#

Tags: c#, unsafe, производительность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каких случаях сборщик мусора не влияет на написанный код?

Блок `unsafe`, вызов функции из библиотеки написанной на другом языке, может еще что то?

Как в таком случае управлять памятью?

Если использовать `unsafe`, это будет касаться всего приложения или только того блока, который пометил ключевым словом `unsafe`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `unsafe` блоки сами по себе не влияют на процесс сборки мусора. То есть даже запиненный с помощью ключевого слова `fixed` блок памяти будет спокойно освожден `Garbage Collector'ом` в тот момент, когда он посчитает, что это можно (или нужно) сделать.
- Опасность выстрелить себе в ногу появляется в двух случаях - в случае использования `IDisposable` объектов и в тот момент, когда в коде появляются использования `Marshal` (типа `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()`).

> - И если для первого кейса, за вычетом нескольких подводных камней, на которые можно нарваться при `COM Interop'e`, все довольно прозрачно - `using`, правильный [`Dispose` паттерн](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fs2xkftw) и внимательное отношение к времени жизни таких объектов, то со вторым все *очень нетривиально.*
> - Во втором случае (когда речь идет о маршаллинге, явном и неявном `COM Interop'a` и работе через вещи типа `IntPtr`) нужно четко и ясно понимать **механику** происходящего - как происходят обращения к `COM` интерфейсам, как работают `managed-to-unmanaged` переходы, где выделяется память и кто отвечает за ее освобождение.

Comment: т.е. писать в Си стиле для повышения производительности критичных участков кода в любом случае не возымеет должного эффекта?

Comment: @Merlin Нужно соотносить цену `managed-unmanaged` перехода и цену ускорения от использования `managed` кода. Иногда вполне себе оправдано выцепить `hotspot` в нативный код, а если функция получается еще и `thread-safe`, то распараллелить ее.